# Observer on customer_register_success event, not called

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer

I've created a custom module, that looks like this:

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycode_GroupRegister>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycode_GroupRegister>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <groupregister>
                <class>Mycode_GroupRegister_Model</class>
            </groupregister>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                    <Mycode_GroupRegister_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Mycode_GroupRegister_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>CustomerRegister</method>
                    </Mycode_GroupRegister_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
        </events>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mycode_GroupRegister before="Mage_Customer">Mycode_GroupRegister</Mycode_GroupRegister>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php
Class Mycode_GroupRegister_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function CustomerRegister($observer)
    {
        die();
        Mage::log('IN CustomerRegister()', null, 'test_register.log');
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('core/app')->getRequest();
        $customer_type = $data->getParam('customer_type');
        try {
            $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

            if ($customer_type == 'wholesale') {
                $customer->setData('group_id',2);
                $customer->setCustomerActivated(0);
                $customer->save();
            } else {
                $customer->setData('group_id',3);
                $customer->save();
            }
            $customer->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::log("Mycode_GroupRegister_Model_Observer failed: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the observer is never called. I have used this extension in another website before and it was working ok. But it's not working on this one.
Could you help me fix it?

Comment: Is it normal registration from magento frontend?

Comment: Yes it is for normal registration

Answer (score 2):

I've tested your code and it works.

You should just remove `die();` from your observer class.

In addition i would recommend to change

```
<class>Mycode_GroupRegister_Model_Observer</class>
```

to

```
<class>groupregister/observer</class>
```

... to avoid problems when using `rewrites` on you observer class.

Comment: @zekia ... did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `config.xml` code like this.

```
<frontend>
    <events>
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                    <Mycode_GroupRegister_Model_Observer>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Mycode_GroupRegister_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>CustomerRegister</method>
                    </Mycode_GroupRegister_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
        </events>
</frontend>
```

Comment: I tried moving event to frontend, as you suggested, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You're extending wrong class. Try extending "Varien_Event_Observer" class.
This will help you access the observer event in the Observer php code.

Comment: Please add more content